# How can a user select a different language to the site default language?

Tags: 6, i18n-l10n

My Drupal 6 site should always display in French for all users *except* me. I need to administer the site in English.

Using the Locale module I have both languages installed and default set to French. In the language negotiation settings ('Configure'), I have selected 'none'. The help text says that *"users may (optionally) select a preferred language on the My Account page"*.

Even though I have selected English in my account settings (under "Language settings"), everything remains in French when I login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to work like that; see [Drupal: changing language settings in user edit not working](http://www.webmaster-forums.net/webmasters-corner/drupal-changing-language-settings-user-edit-not-working).

> If you had the Language negotiation set to *None*, because -- like me -- you thought that would allow users to change their language preferences, you were wrong. The problem is this help text on the Languages page is completely misleading:
>
> > None. The default language is used for site presentation, though users may (optionally) select a preferred language on the My Account page. (User language preferences will be used for site e-mails, if available.)
>
> It should read:
>
> > None. The default language is used for site presentation, though users may (optionally) select a preferred language — for site e-mails, if available — on the My Account page.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the [Administration Language](http://drupal.org/project/admin_language) module?

> This module lets the administrator see all administration pages in her preferred language.
>
> You can use this to display the frontend of the site in one language and still keep most of the backend in English (or another language of your choice).